# java rmi - access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")

Tags: java, rmi

I've seared the web for an answer but nothing helped me.
I'm trying to run an RMI server I created.
in the server main I have this part:

```
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
...
...
...
Naming.rebind("//localhost/ForumSite", obj);
```

my policy file :server,policy(the ... is leading to the folder)-

```
grant codeBase "file:C:/.../workspace//ForunServer/bin/" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1099-", "listen, connect, resolve";

};

grant {
 permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setSecurityManager";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createSecurityManager";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "usePolicy";
  };
```

I'm trying to run a Windows O.S, I wrote in another consloe: javaw rmiregistry
and in another one(from the bin folder):

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=server.policy ServerSideImp
```

I've keep on getting the error:

> access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099"
>   "connect,resolve")

I made sure the policy file is in the same location,

here is the run results when I add -Djava.security.debug=access,failure to the run-

> access: access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "C:\Users...\ForumServer\bin" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setSecurityManager") access: access
>   allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.security.provider.1") access: access allowed
>   ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "getProperty.security.provider.2")
>   access: access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.security.provider.3") access: access allowed
>   ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "getProperty.security.provider.4")
>   access: access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.security.provider.5") access: access allowed
>   ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "getProperty.security.provider.6")
>   access: access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.security.provider.7") access: access allowed
>   ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "getProperty.security.provider.8")
>   access: access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.security.provider.9") access: access allowed
>   ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.security.provider.10") access: access allowed
>   ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.security.provider.11") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "accessClassInPackage.sun.security.provider") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks") access:
>   access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.security.egd"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.securerandom.source") access: access allowed
>   ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "putProviderProperty.SUN") access:
>   access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")
>   access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.arch"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "loadLibrary.net") access: access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\net.dll" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.net.preferIPv4Stack"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "java.net.preferIPv6Addresses" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.net") access: access
>   allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\net.dll" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "impl.prefix" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
>   access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.net.NetPermission" "getNetworkInformation") access: access
>   allowed ("java.net.NetPermission" "getNetworkInformation") access:
>   access allowed ("java.net.NetPermission" "getNetworkInformation")
>   access: access allowed ("java.net.NetPermission"
>   "getNetworkInformation") access: access allowed
>   ("java.net.NetPermission" "getNetworkInformation") access: access
>   allowed ("java.net.NetPermission" "getNetworkInformation") access:
>   access allowed ("java.net.NetPermission" "getNetworkInformation")
>   access: access allowed ("java.net.NetPermission"
>   "getNetworkInformation") access: access allowed
>   ("java.net.NetPermission" "getNetworkInformation") access: access
>   allowed ("java.net.NetPermission" "getNetworkInformation") access:
>   access allowed ("java.net.NetPermission" "getNetworkInformation")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "fileSystemProvider") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.dir" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.version" "read") access:
>   access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.jnu.encoding"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "java.nio.file.spi.DefaultFileSystemProvider" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\URI\AppData\Local\Temp"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "C:\Users\URI\AppData\Local\Temp" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\URI\AppData\Local\Temp" "read")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "loadLibrary.net") access: access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\net.dll" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.nio") access:
>   access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\nio.dll" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.nio.fs.ensureAccurateMetadata"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "java.rmi.server.randomIDs" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.hostname" "read")
>   access: access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.networkaddress.cache.ttl") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.net.inetaddr.ttl" "read") access:
>   access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl") access: access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "URI-PC" "resolve") java.lang.Exception:
>   Stack trace
>           at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
>           at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.(Unknown Source)
>           at ServerSideImp.(ServerSideImp.java:18)
>           at ServerSideImp.main(ServerSideImp.java:62) access: access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "getPolicy") access:
>   access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users...\ForumServer\bin"
>   "read") access: domain that failed ProtectionDomain 
>   (file:/C:/Users/.../ForumServer/bin/ ) 
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93   
>   java.security.Permissions@6f94fa3e (  ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "setSecurityManager")  ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "createSecurityManager")  ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM") 
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "usePolicy") 
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "stopThread") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.arch" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "path.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "line.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.vendor" "read")
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor.url" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.version"
>   "read")  ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.class.version" "read") 
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:0" "listen,resolve") 
>   ("java.io.FilePermission" "\C:\Users...\ForumServer\bin-" "read") )
>
> access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "java.rmi.server.useLocalHostName" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.rmi.transport.logLevel" "read")
>   access: access allowed ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission"
>   "control") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.transport.tcp.logLevel" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control") access:
>   access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.transport.tcp.maxConnectionThreads" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.transport.tcp.threadKeepAliveTime" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.transport.proxy.logLevel" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control") access:
>   access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.transport.proxy.connectTimeout" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.transport.proxy.eagerHttpFallback" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "http.proxyHost" "read")
>   access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "proxyHost"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "java.rmi.server.disableHttp" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.rmi.transport.tcp.readTimeout"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "java.rmi.server.hostname" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.saveGeneratedFiles" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.net") access: access
>   allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\net.dll" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write") access:
>   access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.net.useExclusiveBind" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:0" "listen,resolve") access:
>   access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "modifyThreadGroup") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup") access:
>   access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread") access:
>   access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
>   access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.dgc.logLevel" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control") access:
>   access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "java.rmi.dgc.leaseValue" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.rmi.dgc.checkInterval" "read")
>   access: access allowed ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission"
>   "control") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.runtime.schedulerThreads" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "sun.rmi.runtime.RuntimeUtil.getInstance") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.hostname"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission"
>   "suppressAccessChecks") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader") access:
>   access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "setContextClassLoader") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup") access:
>   access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread") access:
>   access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread") access:
>   access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread") access:
>   access allowed ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission"
>   "suppressAccessChecks") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks") access:
>   access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "java.rmi.server.hostname" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.rmi.transport.connectionTimeout"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "sun.rmi.runtime.RuntimeUtil.getInstance") access: access allowed
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost" "resolve") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "jdk.net.ephemeralPortRange.low" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.net") access: access
>   allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\net.dll" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jdk.net.ephemeralPortRange.high"
>   "read") access: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission"
>   "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve") java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
>           at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
>           at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Unknown Source)
>           at ServerSideImp.main(ServerSideImp.java:63) access: access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "getPolicy") access:
>   access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users...\ForumServer\bin"
>   "read") access: domain that failed ProtectionDomain 
>   (file:/C:/Users/.../ForumServer/bin/ ) 
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93   
>   java.security.Permissions@2c7b84de (  ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "setSecurityManager")  ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "createSecurityManager")  ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM") 
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "usePolicy") 
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "stopThread") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.arch" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "path.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "line.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.vendor" "read")
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor.url" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.version"
>   "read")  ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.class.version" "read") 
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:0" "listen,resolve") 
>   ("java.io.FilePermission" "\C:\Users...\ForumServer\bin-" "read") )
>
> access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM.1")

but I don't really understand whats going here,
any help would be grate.

Comment: *"I've seared the web for an answer"* - I wondered where that burning smell was coming from :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the security manager. You don't need it for RMI unless you're using the RMI codebase feature, which you aren't.

Comment: But, that isn't an exact solution to OP's problem. Also, you can check from his policy file-->`grant {
 permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setSecurityManager";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createSecurityManager";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "usePolicy";
  };`

Comment: @shekharsuman It will do until the real thing comes along. We could go through the whole megillah of `-Djava.security.debug=access,failure` and we would undoubtedly discover that his .policy file isn't being loaded, or being loaded too late, but it's almost certainly pointless. You don't need permission to `setSecurityManager` unless you're already running under a security manager, in which case you can't install another one anyway, so I fail to see the relevance of `setSecurityManager`.

Comment: @EJP I've tried to run it only with java and the file name, still the same error. Do I need to do this in another way?

Comment: @boaz You cannot possibly get a SecurityManager exception unless you are running with a security manager, which is what this answer tells you not to do. So don't do it.